# How to find substring in javascript if index is unknown?

Tags: javascript, substr

Suppose I have a string which contains an HTML file. How do I get the script part only as my sub string?

The example string is :

```
str="<html>...<script>...</script>...</html>"
```

I only need the script part.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function Showques()
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    else 
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    //getting response from servlet
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function();
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
        {
            var localString=xmlhttp.responseText;
            var locationstart =localString.indexOf('<script>');
            var locationend = localString.indexOf('</script>');
            //eval(xmlhttp.responseText);
            document.getElementById("ques").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","XmlApp",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

When I give `</script>` within `indexOf` method it's considering as the end of my script                                 which i declared in the beginning and rest of things I am getting error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this [from](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) aNd [This](http://tomcopeland.blogs.com/juniordeveloper/2006/01/fast_stringinde.html)

```
 String str = "yourStringTosearch"
 int location = str.indexOf('String');
 string.substring(location , to)
```

Ok according to ur example do this

```
 String str = "<html>...<script>...</script>...</html>"
 int locationStart = str.indexOf('<script>');
 int locationend = str.indexOf('</script>');
 strinf finalString =string.substring(locationStart , locationend );   //ur final string value
```

Comment: my string looks like this: str="<html>...<script>...</script>...</html>, i need the script part alone.

Comment: <script type = "text/javascript">

Comment: @user1101422  : this was the output ? <script type = "text/javascript">

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
string.indexOf(searchstring, start)
```

to find the proper index in the string.  You can then use the index in your substr function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: my string looks like this: str="<html>...<script>...</script>...</html>, i need the script part alone.

Answer (score 1):

you should probably better use a dom parser if your string is an actual html file.
If you are working with javascript, here is a simple jQuery way to do it :

```
str="<html>...<script>...</script>...</html>";
$(str).find("script").get(0).outerHtml;
```